# Delete some UL if empty

Tags: php, if-statement, divide

right now my output is something like this
[image]

I want to delete the list that are empty

just tried this code empty or isset inside the listitems

```
<?php if(isset($page)): //but i got different output   ?>
```

even something like

```
<?php if(empty($page): //but i got an error    ?>
```

heres my running code without if statement

```
<?php 
$letter='A';
for($i= 1; $i <=26 ;$i++,$letter++):?>
<?php 

    $pages = $db->prepare("
    SELECT * FROM pages WHERE LEFT(`title`, 1) = '".$letter."'

    ");
    //$check =$db->query("SELECT * FROM watch WHERE animelist_id=".$page['id']." and acc_id=".$_SESSION["user_id"]."");
    $pages->bindParam(1,$letter, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $pages->execute();
?>

<div class = "listitems">

    <?php echo '<h5>'.$letter.'</h5>';?>
            <?php foreach($pages as $page): ?>

                        <ul>
                            <li>
                            <a href="<?php echo BASE_URL;?>/page.php?page=<?php echo e($page['slug']);?>"><?php echo e($page['label']);?></a>

                            </li>
                        </ul>



            <?php endforeach; ?>

</div>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isset()

> it returns true only when the variable is not null.
>   for a empty array, it return true.

empty()

> Determine whether a variable is empty.
>   for a empty array, it return true.

so you should use:

```
if(!empty(pages))
```

Comment: if(!empty($pages)):
insert the ul

else:

endif

Comment: insert it before   <?php foreach($pages as $page): ?>